# How we can handle 50 Dependency injection in single controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, constructor

How we can inject 50 or 100 Injections in laravel ,because if we inject that much,it will not be a good way. It Slows the process.

```
//Just for example : - 
    public function __construct(
    RoleManagement $role_management,
    UserRole $userRole,
    User $user 
    RoleManagement  $role_management,
    UserRole $userRole,
    User $user ,
    RoleManagement $role_management,
    UserRole $userRole,
    User $user ,
    RoleManagement $role_management,
    UserRole $userRole,
    User $user,
    RoleManagement $role_management,UserRole $userRole,User $user)
    {
        $this->role_management     = $role_management;
        $this->userRole     = $userRole;
        $this->user         = $user;
        $this->role_management     = $role_management;
        $this->userRole     = $userRole;
        $this->user         = $user;
        $this->role_management     = $role_management;
        $this->userRole     = $userRole;
        $this->user         = $user;
    }
```

Comment: _it will not be a good way_ No that is correct, it definitely shows signs of bad design. And why are you injecting the same class multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it wouldn't really slow the process as far as I know (the container is compiled, so it comes down to passing parameters during a function call and a few assignation, which is not specifically slower).

Your problem here is a bad design as stated by aynber, your class/method should not depend on that many collaborators.

You can refer more specifically to the S of SOLID (Single Responsibility Principle) and to the [8th object calisthenics](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#8-no-classes-with-more-than-two-instance-variables).

We do not have details on the actual content of the method, but it all comes down to splitting the process in different classes that can be injected one in another.